# What is the best way to handle big media files in MEAN-Stack applications?

Tags: file, amazon-s3, mean-stack, media, video-processing

I have a MEAN-Stack application and I store media files in an AWS S3 Bucket.
Currently I handle the media file upload, in the way that I encode the files in base64 and transfer them with simple post request for each file, over the node.js backend to the S3 Bucked and return the reference link to the file after wards.

That worked well for a time, but now some users decide to upload bigger Files, that party exceeded the size cap of a post call (I think thats 100mb per call, so I capped it to 95mb + 5mb puffer for meta information).

This obviously exceeded the technical capabilities of the application, but also for media files less than that size, it takes a long time for upload and there is no feedback about the uploading progress for the user.

1. What would be the best way to handle big files in the MEAN + S3 Stack?
2. What Angular sided libraries would you suggest? Maybe for video file compression / type conversion (.mov is part of the problem) but also for user feedback
3. Does it make sense to put a data stream through the Node.js server?
4. How would you handle the RAM cap? (currently 512mb per VM(EC2) on which the Node server is hosted).
5. Or what other solutions would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

A small foreword: read about [AWS request-signing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) if you do not already know what it is. This allows your back-end to sign a hash of the parameters of AWS requests so that they can be called by the front end securely. You should actually use this with your existing [GetObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html) requests so that you can control, track, and expire accesses.

> 1. What would be the best way to handle big files in the MEAN + S3 Stack?

Either by uploading directly from the client, or streaming to a server as a [multipart upload to AWS S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html). Note that doing so through the client will require some work as you must call [CreateMultipartUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateMultipartUpload.html) orchestrate the signature of multiple [UploadPart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html) requests on the server, and then call [CompleteMultipartUpload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CompleteMultipartUpload.html).

[Multipart upload limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/qfacts.html) are huge and can handle any scale with your choice of chunk size.

In NodeJS this can actually be done much easier than by handling each command. See the [`@aws-sdk/lib-storage`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html) package, which wraps the upload in a transaction that handles errors and retries.

> 2. What Angular sided libraries would you suggest? Maybe for video file compression / type conversion (.mov is part of the problem) but also for user feedback.

I don't know much about angular, but I would recommend not doing processing of objects on the front-end. A great (and likely cheap) way to accomplish this without a dedicated server is through [AWS lambda functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html) which trigger on object upload. See more about lambda-invocation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-invocation.html).

> 3. Does it make sense to put a data stream through the Node.js server?

It does to me as I mentioned in the answer to question 1, but its not the only way. Lambda functions are again a suitable alternative, or request presigning. See an AWS blog about the issue [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/uploading-to-amazon-s3-directly-from-a-web-or-mobile-application/).

Also [there seems to be way to post from the front-end](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/browser-uploads-to-s3-using-html-post-forms/) directly, and control access through S3 policies.

> 4. How would you handle the RAM cap? (currently 512mb per VM(EC2) on which the Node server is hosted).

Like all performance question, the answer is to *measure*. Monitor the usage of your server in production, and through tests. In addition, its always good to run stress-tests on important architecture. Hammer your architecture (replicated in a development deployment) in emulation of the worst-case, high-volume usage.

What might be most beneficial in your case, is to not run a server, but either a cluster of servers with [autoscaling](https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) and [load balancing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). In addition, [containerization](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) can help decouple physical server deploys and your application. Containers also can use the AWS [Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/), which is a server-less architecture for containers. Containers also mean memory scaling can happen in-process and without much configuration change.

To focus this answer: For your purposes, Fargate or Lambda seem appropriate to provide a server-less architecture.

> 5 Or what other solutions would you suggest?

See above answers.